# ef4 poco,how get id after insert?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am inserting a document and i want references id of document to a part of this 
document...but the code is autoincrement, and i am using poco. how i can get 
back the code of insert file?

```
            ArquivoDTO file = new ArquivoDTO();
            file.NomeArquivo = fileName;
            file.TipoArquivo = fileType;

            file.TamanhoArquivo = fileSize;
            var context = new PROGISContext();
            ArquivoRepository arquivoRepository = new ArquivoRepository(context);
            arquivoRepository.IncluirArquivo(file); //insert file
            ParteArquivoDTO part = new ParteArquivoDTO(); //create a part

            part.CodArquivo = file.CodArquivo; // here id of inserted file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public Guid Identifier { get; protected set; }
```

However you won't get the I'd untill you call `SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to say what's the problem with this code sample alone, but are you calling `SubmitChanges()` on your DataContext in `arquivoRepository.IncluirArquivo(file)`?

If you are, and the CodArquivo property of your ArquivoDTO class it correctly configured to be an auto increment ID, then the property should get updated automatically after SubmitChanges().